# Формат логов для программы парсера логов

Tags: алгоритм, база-данных

Разрабатываю программный комплекс (в него будет входить несколько программ, в дальнейшем возможно расширение комплекса добавлением новых программ) и встал вопрос о формате файла для логов. Проект пишется на C#.

Программы из комплекса будут вести логи своей работы. Вроде бы ничего особого, но я вот задумал такую вещь: чтоб не копаться в логах, не искать что было скажем в пятницу 13-го в 13:13:13, решил создать отдельную программу (нечто парсера логов), которая будет разбирать логи, производить поиск нужной инфы за указанную дату и временной промежуток, и тд. Встал вопрос о том, как организовать логи: в виде файлов или БД с отдельными таблицами под каждую программу.

Я вот на распутье: с одной стороны текстовые файлы удобны, надо будет только разработать собственный формат. Файлы XML, отличный вариант для этой цели. С другой стороны одна БД, но куча таблиц, к тому же, не очень радует перспектива каждый раз создавать новую таблицу (при добавлении новой программы в комплекс). Но за БД выступает SQL, т.е. я смогу проще реализовать идею с данным парсером логов.

В общем я склоняюсь пока к файлам. Может есть более гибкое решение или кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей?

**UPD**

При файловой системе логов - каждый день новый файл (например обзываем файл 04.03.2013 (понедельник), завтра будет 05.03.2012(вторник) и тд.), соот. файлы будут небольшого размера, а БД со временем разрастется и растолстеет. Кол-во файлов тоже будет расти.

Comment: можно исопльзовать готовый лог фреймворк. а можно создать табличку вида: id, time, program_id (fk to programs table), level, message

Comment: например такой - log4net, Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: да, именно этот

Comment: хорошая вещь, но для моих целей не очень подходит

Comment: решил использовать для данных целей SQLite

Comment: Какие же вопросы раньше задавал ) Перечитываешь спустя годы и сам удивляешься. Ну ничего, как же еще учиться, если молчать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем под каждую программу новую таблицу логов? В одну никак что ли не запихнуть?

Сделай там просто 1 поле, которое будет принимать значение программы или нового модуля.

Зачем изобретать каждый раз что-то новое? 1 таблица несколько полей и все.

**//upd**

пыфф

> При файловой системе логов - каждый
> день новый файл (например обзываем
> файл 04.03.2013 (понедельник), завтра
> будет 05.03.2012(вторник) и тд.),
> соот. файлы будут небольшого размера,
> а БД со временем разрастется и
> растолстеет. Кол-во файлов тоже будет
> расти.

WTF???

Ты понял что написал? БД разрастется, а файлы будут небольшого размера. А разница между ними формально то какая будет? 3-5 байт?

Попробуй в файлах сделать поиск потом за 12 марта 2012 года в промежуток с 10:03 по 23:44

Быстро найдешь данные?

Comment: @Shrek не хочется в одну таблицу все сваливать

Comment: А в чем трудности? и второй вопрос, зачем иметь лишние таблицы логов, если они идентичны?

Comment: т.е. Вы предлагаете создать одну таблицу например такого вида ИмяПрограммы|ДатаСообщения|ТекстСообщения и пусть все программы в нее ломятся, записывая данные. А при вводе новой программы кидать в бой ALTER TABLE

Comment: Да, именно так. Это же комплекс программ, они же должны работать как-то вместе.

Или логика работы этого комплекса иная?

Comment: Вам + к ответу, спасибо большое! Однако я пока еще поэкспериментирую и посмотрю, может кто еще выскажется по данному вопросу

Comment: А что плохого в большой таблице? Никто не мешает ведь периодически удалять из нее логи, которые уже не нужны.

Comment: логи могут храниться продолжительное время, может полгода, может и более. Кстати спасибо за коммент, подали идею к функционалу вьювера логов ))

Comment: А разве эта таблица будет огромной?
Вот у меня на работающем сайте инет магазина есть таблица в неё постоянно пишутся логи, каждые 15 минут. сейчас в ней около 6 миллионов записей весит 64.7МБ, постоянно оптимизируется средствами phpmyadmin. это около полугода логов. Это разве много?

Вот если бы эта таблица весила 1-3Гб тогда да - много, а то что она в год вываливается за 100Мб - это копейки. Это ведь логи, они могут пригодиться всегда :) И как обычно в логи пишутся ошибки, а не все подряд, если это не система логирования действий пользователя в админках :) там все писать нужно.

Answer (score 0):

А че-то не догоняю - зачем такая программа? Есть же в конце-то концов [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) - сделанный на основе де-факто промышленного стандарта для Java логгинга - Log4J.

Декларируйте ему `Appender`, который пишет логи в БД и все. Например, не вижу чем плох [AdoNetAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html)

Или я в чем-то неправ?